# Which property do I use to align my logo with my navigation?

Tags: html, css, header

I asked a related question a few minutes ago through which I got this updated code but I can't figure out how to get my logo to show up on the left hand side.

HTML:

```
 <header>
 <img src="/images/logo.png" height="50px" id="front" />
 <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 <div id="second_line"></div>
 </header>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
 margin: 0;
 }
 header {
 background-color: #009000;
 height: 85px;
 position: relative;
 }
 #front {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }
 nav {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 30px;
 }
 ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 }
 ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 border-right: 2px solid black;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 }
 ul li.last {
 border-right: 0px;
 }
 #second_line {
 margin-top:10px;
 height:3px;
 background-color: #FECE2C;
 }
```

How do I fix this so that the logo is on the left not the right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
header > img {float:left;}
```

Comment: How big your image in width px and height px?

Comment: 1538px x 288px but i am resizing it to 50px in the img tag.

Comment: try adding this before the "<div id="second_line"></div>" -> <div style="clear:both;"></div>

Comment: That last part worked.  I probably would have never guessed using that.  How do I learn this stuff the right way?

Comment: Clearing floats are hard to learn by reading, it is one of those things that come after a few times of doing it, a tip though is that if you are using floats, you should probably be using clear:both; at some point :)

Comment: Btw I am trying to increase the size of the divider between the menu options but can't seem to find a way.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: ul li {
 border-right: 4px solid black;
 } - this will increase the width if that is what you mean - its currently: border-right: 2px solid black;

Comment: @danilel thakns for replying.  But i actually mean the length of the divider.

Comment: Ah I see, try adding "line-height:30px;" to the ul li { }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20292/discussion-between-kpo-and-daniel)

Answer (score 1):

You might try adjusting the `<nav>` to [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display#Values):

```
nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/petFT/)

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56ycJ/1/)

you just miss adding this style.

```
header img{float:left;}
```

Comment: I tried that before but doing that makes the logo aligned but the header then gets messed up.  Try using an image in your example as a logo and you'll see what i mean..

Comment: It still gives me the same issue.  The logo aligns but the header goes down.

Comment: You forgot to add the second_line in the html.